# Faraday conflicts in google_drive and google-api-client

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-api-client, google-drive-api, faraday

I'd like to be able to use both the google-api-client gem to do service to service authentication and the google_drive api to access spreadsheets.  Unfortunately, these gems seem to conflict due to requiring different versions of Faraday in their dependencies.  Anyone know how to solve this?

Error if google_drive is required first:

```
specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate google-api-client-0.4.4, because faraday-0.8.1 conflicts with faraday (~> 0.7.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Error if google/api_client comes first:

```
specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate oauth2-0.7.1, because faraday-0.7.6 conflicts with faraday (~> 0.8) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give me an day or so and I'll update the google-api-client gem to use the more recent version of Faraday.

That said, you shouldn't need a separate gem to use Google Drive, and any gem designed to add syntactic sugar to a discovery based Google API should really be using the official gem as a base.

Comment: Just wanted to give an update on this because it's actually been closer to a month than a day. Got hung up on some issues with JRuby and signature verification that are preventing a release. The problem is with a downstream dependency we don't control. Patch has been submitted, just waiting for it to be applied and released.

Comment: Signet has been updated to work with Faraday 0.8.x, but still working through some issues with conflicting dependencies in Autoparse and the client itself.

Comment: Can we require an older version of this gem in order to avoid this conflict?

Comment: Yes, but I recommend doing so only via a Gemfile. A release will be coming very, very soon, now that Launchy has been updated. Hopefully within a few hours actually, since I'm working on it right now.